# locking on target

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having problem with locking one object on another.
Lets image an turret which always targets flying plane.
I come to this solution:

1. Compute `yaw = atan2(z2-z1, x2-x1)`
2. Compute `pitch = atan2(y2-y1, z2-z1)`
3. Rotate

What do you think about such method? Is there any "faster" way without using `atan2`?
Can I achieve same effect with just quaternions operations?

Comment: Is this two questions? What are you asking? It looks to me like you asked a question about having a turret face an object, then gave us some unrelated code about orbital motion without even telling us what you want to know about it.

Comment: like pictures show,I want my origin point to be in the center of orbiting objects not a part of the path just like it is now.

Comment: You're still asking two questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an object A to point towards a point B, then it's not difficult.

```
Vector current_heading = non_rotated_heading_of_object * object->rotation;
Vector target_heading = (target_position - object->position).normalize();
Vector axis = current_heading.cross(target_heading);
float angle = std::acos(current_heading.dot(target_heading));
Quaternion rotation = rotateAngleAxis(axis, angle);
```